# How do I not get an OkPacket with my RowDataPacket in nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js

When doing a query on my database I only want the RowDataPacket back, not an OkPacket. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Had to specify [0] on the result so that only the RowDataPacket was returned